# Changing the value of a variable with DOM element click

Tags: javascript, dom

Im trying to allow the player to click the Rock paper or scissors button and that changes the value of the 'playerChoice' variable so so the playRound function can be called with their choice but it doesnt seem to work and im not sure what im doing wrong

Code

```
// Rock paper scissors game
let rockBtn = document.querySelector('.Rock');
let paperBtn = document.querySelector('.Paper');
let scissorBtn = document.querySelector('.Scissors');



function computerPlay() {
    let rps = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    let computerChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random()*rps.length)];
    return computerChoice;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {


    if (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        console.log('Its a Draw');

    } else if (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Player wins");

    } else if(playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        console.log("Computer wins");

    } else if(playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        console.log("Its a draw");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Computer wins");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        console.log("Player wins");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Its a draw");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        console.log("Player wins ");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        console.log("Computer wins");
    }

    
}

function game() {

    const computerChoice = computerPlay();
    var playerChoice = "";

    rockBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
        playerChoice = "Rock";
    });

    paperBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
        playerChoice = "Paper";
        console.log(playerChoice);
    });

    scissorBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
        playerChoice = "Scissors";
    });

    console.log("Player choice is" + playerChoice);
    console.log('Computer choice is' + computerChoice);
    
    


    playRound(playerChoice, computerChoice);



}


game();
```

Is this the correct way to do this is there a better way?

Comment: Instead of checking all for draw, you can: `if (playerSelection == computerSelection) console.log('Its a Draw');`

Comment: event listeners should be declared one, i think, and not withing game().

Comment: see my comments on @Dipansh's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `playRound` method inside the click listeners.

```
// Rock paper scissors game
let rockBtn = document.querySelector('.Rock');
let paperBtn = document.querySelector('.Paper');
let scissorBtn = document.querySelector('.Scissors');

var playerChoice = "";

function computerPlay() {
    let rps = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    let computerChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random()*rps.length)];
    return computerChoice;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        console.log('Its a Draw');

    } else if (playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Player wins");

    } else if(playerSelection == "Rock" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        console.log("Computer wins");

    } else if(playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        console.log("Its a draw");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Computer wins");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Paper" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        console.log("Player wins");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Scissors") {
        console.log("Its a draw");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Paper") {
        console.log("Player wins ");
    } else if(playerSelection == "Scissors" && computerSelection == "Rock") {
        console.log("Computer wins");
    }

    playerChoice = "";
}

rockBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
   playerChoice = "Rock";
   playRound(playerChoice, computerPlay());
});

paperBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
   playerChoice = "Paper";
   playRound(playerChoice, computerPlay());
});

scissorBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
   playerChoice = "Scissors";
   playRound(playerChoice, computerPlay());
});
```

Comment: Inside event listener function, when calling playRound, send playerChoice and send computerChoise as what is returned from function computerPlay(), directry.  Example for Rock: 
`rockBtn.addEventListener('click' , function() {
    playRound("Rock", computerPlay());
  });`

Comment: Yeah I get it, I just didn't add that part of the code. I'll update the whole code.

Comment: Good Job!
event listeners should be declared one, i think, and not withing game().